# If I run a migration with Django South and it crashes, is my database ever corrupted?

Tags: mysql, django, django-south, data-integrity

I'm playing around with Django South, and have been impressed by it's power, but in the process of doing some migrations, I've managed to do things that cause errors in the middle of migrations.  Things like having a syntax error or run time exception in a data migration file, deciding I didn't want to actually do something and hitting ctrl-c during a migration and aborting prematurely, etc.

I'm using MySQL as a database backend.  Do I need to worry about the integrity of my database when something goes wrong with South?  Do transactions ensure that all problems are rolled back on error?

Comment: 1) Does it uses transactions? 2) Do those transactions cover DDL statements in MySQL?

Comment: The storage method on my database is InnoDB, which supports transactions.  From my googling, it doesn't appear InnoDB's transactions cover DDL statements.  So I guess that means a data migration would be covered, but a schema migration wouldn't?  It seems that schema migrations are easier to get right the first time since the system can automate most of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database should rollback nicely:

http://south.aeracode.org/docs/migrationstructure.html#transactions

Anyway, can't you just check the db tables?

A couple of notes:

- You can print the existing migrations with

  > manage.py migrate --list

  This also shows which migrations have been applied
- You can also manually rollback to a previous migration using

  > manage.py migrate <app_name> 0010

  where 10 is the last safe migration

Hope this helps

Comment: "Anyway, can't you just check the db tables?" - It doesn't matter much on my dev database, but if I were to use this on a production database, I would want to make sure it didn't break.  I suppose that is why you would not try it on the production database before testing it on dev.